# Can't compile GLUT helloworld with MinGW

Tags: windows, opengl, cmake, mingw, glut

I'd like to setup OpenGL libraries and run a simple GL programm:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Gl/glut.h>

int main()
{
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f (0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm building project using CLion and therefore here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(MuspellsheimR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MuspellsheimR ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I've downloaded GLUT [here](https://code.google.com/p/rawvideoplayer/downloads/detail?name=glut-3.7.6-bin.zip&can=2&q=) and put glut.dll into C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (and in C:\Windows\System32 just in case), glut.h to C:\MinGW\include\GL and glut32.lib to C:\MinGW\lib.
Here's output message I get:

```
CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:486: undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit@12'
CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:503: undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:549: undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
PATH/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
PATH/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
PATH/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glOrtho@48'
PATH/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `glBegin@4'
PATH/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
PATH/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
PATH/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
PATH/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
PATH/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `glEnd@0'
PATH/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `glFlush@0'
```

Comment: what error messages do you get?

Comment: @m.s. ah, ye, sure. Adding to the post.

Comment: Never put stuff like `glut.dll` in `C:\Windows`. Ever. Just put it next to your executable.

Comment: @rubenvb, doesn't work either. still getting same error output

Comment: That wasn't meant to solve your issue, the answer by @m.s. solves your issue (which is not linking to the glut library).

Comment: By the way, even if you link the glut.dll, your code will not work. You need to initilize your opengl window first using glut. Then write a display function and put your drawing codes there.Finally attach your display function to your opengl window.

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/)

Comment: It would help us to help you, if in addition to the error messages, you showed the full text of the command which mingw32-make was trying to execute, and hence, from which they originate.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you let CMake handle the dependencies using `find_package`.
You are definitely missing the linking step:

```
project(MuspellsheimR)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(MuspellsheimR ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MuspellsheimR ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} )
```

Comment: alright, now I got `No rule to make target 'C:/Windows/System32/glut32.dll', needed by 'executable.exe'.  Stop.`

Comment: @arcadia Do you have that file? In any case, after your `find_package`, add `message (STATUS "GLUT_LIBRARY = ${GLUT_LIBRARY}")` and post your cmake output

Comment: @Antonio, I get `GLUT_LIBRARY = C:/Windows/System32/glut32.dll`, and then the same `mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Windows/System32/glut32.dll', needed by 'MuspellsheimR.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MuspellsheimR.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MuspellsheimR.dir/rule] Error 2`

Comment: The library must be a `.a` file, i.e. `libglut32.a`

Comment: @arcadia Do you have that dll file? Check where is your actual glut installation. And check [this link](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/): to my knowledge they are the best binaries you can find for glut for windows.

Comment: @arcadia Are you doing something strange like `add_library(GLUT_LIBRARY ...)`? You CMakeLists.txt should be essentially as m.s. posted, and nothing more

Comment: My CMakeLists only has two more lines: require proper CMake version and set GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR. Nothing else.

Comment: @arcadia Try all of the following: 1) Run cmake and build from a clean directory 2) Remove the set GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR you just mentioned, as it is already included in g.s's code.

Comment: @m.s.: the library does not need to be libglut.a; MinGW's GCC can link directly with glut.dll, provided glut.dll is in the default library search path, or its directory is specified (usually with a -L option), in the link command.

Comment: @arcadia: Why is glut.dll specified as a build prerequisite, in your generated makefile? It should normally not be, but should simply be listed as a library to search at link time, (traditionally by adding it to the `LIBS` makefile variable). Also, why does mingw32-make believe it is a prerequisite with an explicit path of C:/Windows/System32, if you've moved it elsewhere?